# Calling a cpp extern function with function pointer from c# throws System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++

I have a cpp program with two function pointers as parameter and which in turn will call a third party dll. And I need to call it from my c#. But on runtime I get the errror System.AccessViolationException'

My c# code is

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void initDelegate1(int a, uint b);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void initDelegate2(uint a);

[DllImport("MyAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void APIInit2(initDelegate1 a, initDelegate2 b);

private static initDelegate1 initDel1;
private static initDelegate2 initDel2;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    initDel1 = new initDelegate1(InitCB1);
    initDel2 = new initDelegate2(InitCB2);

    var dell1 = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(initDel1);
    var dell2 = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(initDel2);
    APIInit2(initDel1, initDel2);
}

public static void InitCB1(int var1, uint var2)
{

}

public static void InitCB2(uint var1)
{

}
```

And my cpp method is

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void APIInit2(event_cb evt, heartbeat_cb hbEvt)
{
    std::cout << "Success call";

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"MyAPI.dll");
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDLL), "init");
    initFunc initFn = initFunc(lpfnGetProcessID);

    initFn(serviceId, fsaAddress.c_str(), port, evt, hbEvt);
}
```

Where the definition of event_cb is

```
typedef void(__stdcall* event_cb)(int service_id, event_id_t event_id
```

and the definition of heartbeat_value is

```
typedef void(__stdcall* heartbeat_cb)(unsigned int heartbeat_value);
```

Comment: OK, so which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: If I comment the line 
initFn(serviceId, fsaAddress.c_str(), port, evt, hbEvt);
it calls successfully. Does this give you any hint?

Comment: There are too many moving parts here. It could be that `init` in `MyAPI.dll` does not have a signature that matches `initFunc`. It could be that `fsaAddress` is invalid, `port` is invalid, `evt` is invalid, `hbEvt` is invalid or that `LoadLibrary` failed or that `GetProcAddress` failed... You will have to do some debugging here to narrow down the cause.

Comment: I am getting error 193 in the GetLastError after I called LoadLibrary.